# how to concate variables in url_for jinja2 flask?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

In url_for filename I want to concat `id` variable but I don't know how to do this?

```
{% set userid=post.author.id %}
{% set mediafile=post.media %}
{% set path = url_for('static',filename='post_media/{userid}/{mediafile}')%}
<div>
   <img style="height: 100%; width:100%;" class="article-img" src="{{ path }}">
</div>
```

Comment: Did you trying using `f-string`?

Comment: f string doesn't work in html jinja2

Comment: `url_for('static', filename='post_media/' ~ userid ~ '/post.media')`

Comment: what you told its working but in the same way i am trying to concat 2nd variable but it's not working 
```
% set userid=post.author.id %}
{% set mediafile=post.media %}
{% set path = url_for('static', filename='post_media/' ~ userid ~ '/~ mediafile ~')%}
```
@β.εηοιτ.βε

Comment: @zircon everything in quotes (`'`) are static strings, so, if you want a variable, you need to end the string and use the concatenation operator (`~`). So: `{% set path = url_for('static', filename='post_media/' ~ userid ~ '/' ~ mediafile)%}`